# Longest Subsequence with given conditions

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given an array *A* having *n* elements and integer *k*. I need to find longest subsequence beginning with the first element of array and the **total weight of the the subsequence is ≤ k.** 
Weight of the subsequence is defined as **sum of absolute difference of consecutive elements of choosen subsequence**.

**Constraints** : - 
1 ≤ n ≤10^5 
0 ≤ k ≤50
0 ≤ Ai≤ 50
Example: *n*= 4, *k* = 5, *A* = [1, 2, 50, 6]

Answer: the longest valid subsequence, **[1, 2, 6]**, has length **3**.
Weight of the subsequence is |1 - 2| + |2 - 6| = 1 + 4 = 5.
Note that the subsequence begins with the first element of the array.

I think this problem can be solved using Dynamic Programming but I am not able to come up with the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you're working through the array A, selecting values to include in your subsequence. At each step, you can either (a) include the current value, or (b) not include it. If you memoize the better of these two options, then it should be possible to get dynamic programming working.

In pseudocode, your function should look something like this:

```
int longest_subseq(ix, available_weight, last_val):
    # Parameters:
    # ix = an index into array A (assumed to have global scope)
    # available_weight = the remaining weight avaiable for the subsequence
    #                    starting at ix
    # last_val = the last value in the subsequence from A[0] through A[ix-1]

    # When first called, create a DP array of 10^5 × 51 × 51 elements
    # (This will use about 1GB of memory, which I assume is OK)
    if DP is undefined:
        DP = new array(100001, 51, 51)
        initialize every element of DP to -1

    # Return memoized value if available
    v = DP[ix, available_weight, last_val]
    if v >= 0:
        return v

    # Check for end conditions
    if ix == n or available_weight == 0:
        return 0

    # Otherwise you have two options; either include A[ix] in the
    # subsequence, or don't include it
    len0 = longest_subseq(ix+1, available_weight, last_val)
    if abs(A[ix] - last_val) > available_weight:
        DP[ix, available_weight, last_val] = len0
        return len0
    len1 = 1 + longest_subseq(ix+1, available_weight-abs(A[ix]-last_val), A[ix])
    if len0 > len(1):
        DP[ix, available_weight, last_val] = len0
        return len0
    else:
        DP[ix, available_weight, last_val] = len1
        return len1
```

If you then call `longest_subseq(0, k, A[0])`, the function should return the correct answer in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I think we can use the fact that when you have [a,b,c] then only a and c matters as b gets canceled out.

Comment: @squeamish-ossifrage, your solution is giving wrong answer for:
n = 5, k = 0, and A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Answer should be 5 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], please can you look into it once.

Comment: Ah, OK. `if A[ix] > available_weight` about 2/3 of the way down should read `if abs(A[ix] - last_val) > available_weight`. There are probably other errors too, but this is just pseudocode. If you can figure out what it's trying to do, then it shouldn't be too hard to get a working implementation.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I tried with n = 9, k = 10 and A = [5 2 4 9 1 3 2 4 5], but again it is giving me wrong answer...Can you please help me out...Here is my code Link:
https://ideone.com/6kI7iZ

Correct answer should be 7 [5 2 4 3 2 4 5] but giving 5 as answer instead.